# Excel Object Model and its members

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me understand what might be a basic question? In the Excel Object Model, under `View` >> `Object Browser`, why do the majority of the Excel Classes listed have `Application` as one of its members? I thought the application was the top level object in the hierarchy. Can someone give a brief explanation?

Comment: Really interesting.  It is indeed the top level object.

Comment: Probably for the same reason a ton of them have a `.Parent` property.  It's so you can traverse the object hierarchy in both directions if given an arbitrary object.

Comment: In sufficiently generic VBA code you might need to know what application a passed object is part of.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that makes sense. I found this example on MSDN but it doesn't work for me: `Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet") 
xl.Application.Workbooks.Open "newbook.xls"
`. Is this what you and @Comintern mean?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) is the link to MSDN.

Comment: Looking at the MSDN article, it seems like automating one application from another (or from VBScript) might be a common use-case for this. If you are writing Word code which is controlling Excel, and you have a variable for an Excel object, you might need to use that object's `Application` property to get to certain settings or methods.

Comment: I was thinking something more like `If mySheet.Parent Is ActiveWorkbook Then ...` or `myBook.Application.Quit`

Answer (score 0):

The USA have states, each state has cities, each city has citizens.

Every citizen has the USA as her-his country. USA is an attribute of every citizen. In the same way, every city has the USA as its country. USA is an attribute of every city. And the same happens with every object in the USA hierarchy.

Excel has workbooks and each workbook has a Excel as its parent. No matter how downward you go in the Excel object model hierarchy, every Excel object has Excel as its top level object. All the objects come from Excel.

Keep in mind that the Application property is just an attribute. It's read-only.

For example, the expression below will return "Microsoft Excel"

AppAtribute = ThisWorkbook.Application

AppAtribute = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Application

You can better understand this concept if you see the Excel hierarchy as a map. Download an Excel object model map at the bottom of this article: [The Excel object model demystified](https://www.wizdoh.com/excel-vba-object-model-demystified/)